# Releasing unused pages in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a separate `.h`, `.m`, and `.xib` files for each `UIViewController` based page of a `UIPageViewController` based picture book.  Each page is loaded with animations, music, etc. and takes about 4MB of memory. In Instruments, the free memory drops down about 4MB as each page is loaded.  This memory is never released as the pages are turned.  It eventually gives memory warnings.  `UIPageViewController` seems to keep each page it instantiates in memory and won't unload it.  So when pages are turned fast, the app crashes.

I would like to be able to unload all pages except the 3 needed by `UIPageViewController` - the previous, current, and next pages.  How can I unload undesired pages since they were instantiated by `UIPageViewController`.

Below is the Array of the pages that `UIPageViewController` pulls from.  All of the pages (Page1, Page2, etc.) basically just load image files, provide basic animation, and have music.

```
    //ARRAY OF PAGES    
pageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        (id)[[Page1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],
            [[Page2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],    
            [[Page3 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],    
            [[Page4 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],    
            [[Page5 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],    
            [[Page6 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil], 
            [[Page7 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],
            [[Page8 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],
             // continues all the way up to page 47
             [[Page47 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil],
             nil];
```

I've left out the standard initialization for `UIPageViewController`.  It uses "`nextPageNumber`" to pull the right page from the `pageArray` above to create a new page object.

```
-(void)turnPageForward{

[pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[pageArray objectAtIndex:nextPageNumber]]
                         direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                          animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){
                          }];
```

}

I have tried creating an object "`pageIndex`" (see below) that is set to nil after providing it to the `pageController`.  It didn't work.  The page still took up memory well after the pages had advanced.

```
//PROGRAM PAGE FORWARD
```

-(void)turnPageForward{

```
UIViewController * pageIndex =[pageArray objectAtIndex:nextPageNumber];  //nextPageNumber is the next page to load

[pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pageIndex]
                         direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
                          animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){
                          }];                                  
pageIndex = nil;
```

}

I've looked through stackoverflow for posts using the same way of supplying pages to `UIPageViewController`, but haven't found anything close.  The closest was "*ARC not releasing memory when going “back” in navigation controller*" but doesn't set the view controllers the same way.

I've tried to set the undesired pages to nil so ARC can remove them with no luck.  Any suggestions or alternate paths I should try?  I like the page curl effect and have not been able to find a good one elsewhere that does horizontal page curls.

Thanks!  Eric

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"UIPageViewController seems to keep each page it instantiates in memory"

No, you're doing that by instantiating all those "pages" (controllers), and putting them into an array (the memory jumps as you turn the page because the controller's view is not actually loaded until you display it, even though the controller has been instantiated. But once you've done that, your controller retains its view and the array retains the controller). You just need to keep some kind of count of which page you're on, and in the implementation of viewControllerBeforeViewController: and viewControllerAfterViewController:, instantiate a page there. When you go away from that page, its controller will be dealloc'd. If the loading is slow, you might need to keep an array that has the current page and the ones before and after -- UIPageViewController does do that if you have it set to scroll instead of page curl for the transition.

I made a simple test app like this:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    int count;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    count = 1;
    self.pager = [[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward options:nil];
    self.pager.dataSource = self;
    self.pager.delegate = self;
    Page1 *first = [[Page1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page1" bundle:nil];
    [self.pager setViewControllers:@[first] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pager];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pager.view];
    [self.pager didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}


-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (count > 1) {
        NSString *nibName = [@"Page" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",count-1];
        UIViewController *prev = [[NSClassFromString(nibName) alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
        count -= 1;
        return prev;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (count < 3) {
        NSString *nibName = [@"Page" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",count+1];
        UIViewController *next = [[NSClassFromString(nibName) alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
        count += 1;
        return next;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

My example only has 3 pages, but it illustrates one way to do this. I put logs in the dealloc methods of the 3 controllers, and they were called when I navigated away from them.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the friendly explanation!    The pages are calling dealloc just fine now.  I do have a follow on question though.  The memory is still not being released. Should I be individually releasing objects within the dealloc method?  

I also see that viewWillUnload and ViewDidUnload are not called for any of the pages afterwards.

Any thoughts?  I will gladly investigate this further, but maybe you have a likely path I can research.

Thanks

Eric

Comment: I apologize. I did not mean to put viewWillUnload (no such thing).  Also, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear do occur for each page, just not viewDidUnload.

Comment: @EricAdvance, how do you know that the memory is not being released? If you're using ARC, it should be. You don't need to release the views in dealloc under ARC, that's done for you. Are you keeping any references to these objects, or are they all owned by the views? As for why viewWillDisappear isn't called, I don't know.

Comment: @EricAdvance, I just tested mine, and viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear are both being called.

Comment: @EricAdvance, viewDidUnload has been depreciated and is no longer called. This was normally called in low memory situations, where the system would release memory of those views while the controller was still alive -- that doesn't matter in your case because you're controllers are being dealloc'd, and the views will be too.

Comment: Thanks for your help again.  I see you were up late answering this!  With your help, I believe everything is being called as it should – Dealloc, viewWillDisappear, and viewDidDisappear.  

In Instruments, Free memory continues to decrease with each page until a memory warning.  The app does not crash as inactive memory is pulled from to assist.

I am using the programmatic way of changing pages instead of using the gestures based page transition.  I need to study and test more this weekend and let you know what I find.   Suggested paths to investigate? 

 Eric

Comment: @EricAdvance, If you're doing it like I showed, but inside your turnPageForward method, I don't see why it should be doing that unless you're holding onto those resources somewhere else. I really can't offer any more advice without seeing more of the program.

Comment: I will dig into it more this weekend using your example as the starting point and going from there.  Hopefully I can figure out where I went astray!  Eric

Comment: @rdalmer, I’ve updated my code without good results.  I filled out the code you supplied with 11 dummy pages, each containing random photos with the intent of watching what occurs in Instruments.  I ran it on an iPhone with other apps running to make sure the free memory available was fairly small.  Unfortunaely, Free memory still reduces page by page until a memory warning occurs and other apps are closed.  It is then supplemented by the inactive memory.   I can get you a copy of the code if you have time either by GIT or dropbox.  No problem if you're busy though.  Thanks!  Eric

Comment: @EricAdvance. I should have time to look at it. Can you put it on GitHub? Or, you can just email it to me at rdelmar@comcast.net

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit older, but maybe my approach can help some people facing the same issue when not using ARC.

I think the best way to release unused pages is in the didFinishAnimation method of the UIPageViewController. You get the 1 or 2 previous view controllers there and you can easily release them. I do it like this:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)thePageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {

    if(completed) {
        for (UIViewController *viewController in previousViewControllers) {
             [viewController release];
        }
     }
}
```

It is important that you only release them if the action was completed because otherwise with the next page change you would try to access released pages.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem this time.
And after an hour thinking,I had find a solution.

This is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BKContentViewController : UIPageViewController

@end
```

And my .m file and viewDidload method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;

    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:detailContent]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO
                  completion:NULL];
}
```

And the most important.

```
#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDataSource UIPageViewControllerDelegate

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{
    if (completed) {
        [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:detailContent]
                       direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                        animated:NO
                      completion:NULL];
    }

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{


    if (!detailRight) {
        detailRight = [[DetailContent alloc] init];
        [detailRight setShouldReturn:YES];
        [detailRight setPath:fPath withFileName:fName];
    }
    return detailRight;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    if (!detailLeft) {
        detailLeft = [[DetailContent alloc] init];
        [detailLeft setShouldReturn:YES];
        [detailLeft setPath:fPath withFileName:fName];
    }

    return detailLeft;
}

- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
    [self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    self.doubleSided = NO;
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
}
```

After this, I have only three viewContrller and the memory will not increase by scroll again and again.
Hope this will help you.