# receiving memory warning in simple uipageviewcontroller app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, didreceivememorywarning

I have a uipageviewcontroller app based on the default page based app available as a starting point in xcode 7.1

My data controller looks like the following:

```
@interface DataViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *descTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *backgroundView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *startAgainButton;
- (IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startAgainButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation DataViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject title];
    self.backgroundImage.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:[self.dataObject imageName]];
    self.descTextView.text = [self.dataObject desc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
```

My model controller has looks like the following:

```
@interface ModelController ()

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageData;
@end

@implementation ModelController

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _pageData = [self loadPageData];

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)loadPageData{
    //255 173 80
    NewsPoint *newspoint1 = [[NewsPoint alloc] init];
    newspoint1.title = @"my title";
    newspoint1.tintCode = @" ";
    newspoint1.imageName = @"news";
    newspoint1.desc = @"my desc"

return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:newspoint1, newspoint2, newspoint3, newspoint4, newspoint5, newspoint6, newspoint7, nil];
}
```

When I receive my memory warning my app goes unresponsive and I can no longer swipe between views.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Click ``debug / pause`` and see what main thread does

Answer (score 0):

Your application may receive Memory Warning because you instantiate all ViewControllers at launch.

You should not store viewControllers in an NSArray but instantiate them only when you need it.

Take a look at this answer : [Releasing unused pages in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14756477/4320246)